# Add unique class to webform radio form-item div

Tags: theming, webforms

Can anyone point me in the right direction to show, how to add a unique class to the webform select options container divs .form-item? I would like to theme these divs surrounding the each radio button with a different background image. I don't really care what the class is, numbers, the key, etc. just as long as I can target it in my css.

Answer (score 0):

You can add particular css while creating that field in webform configuration itself.See below section in your webform
[image]

For this particular clas you can add css in your code.

Comment: Indeed, I know that is there. I was referring to putting a unique class on each radio button to style each option differently.